# Javascript modify public properties from private functions

Tags: javascript, class, oop, properties, private-functions

I coded a class in JavaScript, and I'm trying to modify one of my public properties inside a private function.

Here is an example of my code:

```
MyClass = function(callback){

    this.tabs = [];
    var tabs_callback = function(){};

    this.setTabsCallback = function(callback) {
        tabs_callback = callback;
    }

    var _doStuff = function(callback) {

        // doing stuff

        this.tabs = [1, 2, 3];

        console.log("Inside doStuff");
        console.log(this.tabs);

        tabs_callback();
    }

    this.doStuff = function() {
        _doStuff();
    }
}


var myObject = new MyClass();

myObject.setTabsCallback(function () {

    console.log("Inside callback");
    console.log(myObject.tabs);
});

myObject.doStuff();
```

And here is what I get in the console:

```
Inside doStuff
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
Inside callback
[]
```

Why am I not able to see my modification from the callback function?

Comment: Probably the scope of `this`. Up at the top of the `MyClass` function (perhaps the line above `this.tabs = [];`) create a variable `var self = this;` and use `self` in place of `this` where you want to access the public properties.

Comment: Oh great! You're right, it worked! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `_doStuff` is defined as a function, it has its own `this` context, which is why you cannot access the `this.tabs` that you defined outside of the private function.

There are two simple ways to resolve this.

First, you can simply create a private variable which holds a reference to `this` outside the function:

```
...
var that = this;
var _doStuff = function(callback) {
    // inside _doStuff, use "that" instead of "this"
...
```

Or, second, you could instead use an arrow function. Arrow functions are a relatively new addition to Javascript. They do not create a separate context with its own `this` reference, so when you use the `this` object it will still refer to the same object as outside the function, so your function will work correctly:

```
....
var _doStuff = (callback) => {
    // now _doStuff doesn't create a new "this" object, so you can still access the one from outside
...
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context). Using arrow functions is a good way to prevent many of these issues:

`var _doStuff = (callback) => { ...`

Yet you still need to be aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

By default, JS does not use lexical context binding, and when you call ordinary functions, `this` defaults to `window` (or `null` if you are in strict mode).

There are plenty of ways to avoid it: you can save `this` to variable, as mentioned above. It will work in 100% of cases.

Also you can explicitly bind _doStuff to context, using `Function#bind` method: do something like `_doStuff = _doStuff.bind(this)` after it's initialization or you may call it like `_doStuff.bind(this)()`. IEs prior to IE9 (and, maybe, some other browsers, I'm not quite sure) don't support `bind`.

In the end, you can use arrow function, as it also mentioned above: they use lexical binding and `this` will be same as you expect. Arrow functions available since ES6, but, I suppose, if you are making constructors like this, it's not ES6.

Answer (score 1):

When `_doStuf` is invoked through a function like

```
this.doStuff = function() {
                 _doStuff();
               }
```

`_doStuff` is bound to the global object. Hence you should either bind it's definition to the `this` or use `.call(this)` when invoking `_doStuff` function. So modifying your code as follows will help;

```js
MyClass = function(callback){

    this.tabs = [];
    var tabs_callback = function(){};

    this.setTabsCallback = function(callback) {
        tabs_callback = callback;
    }

    var _doStuff = function(callback) {

        // doing stuff

        this.tabs = [1, 2, 3];

        console.log("Inside doStuff");
        console.log(this.tabs);

        tabs_callback();
    } // <<< you can either use .bind(this) here 

    this.doStuff = function() {
        _doStuff.call(this);  // <<< or use .call(this) here to bind _doStuff to the this
    }
}


var myObject = new MyClass();

myObject.setTabsCallback(function () {

    console.log("Inside callback");
    console.log(myObject.tabs);
});

myObject.doStuff();
```